# How to change UI language in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

How to change UI language in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) (1.0 released April 2016)?

[image: Chinese]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See "Display Language" https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

I had trouble with this and the answer from Eric Bole-Feysot did not help as it is missing an important step.

1. Open VS Code
2. Press F1
3. Type "configure display language"
4. Select "configure display language" from the options displayed beneath the inputbox
5. Change JSON to

> `"locale": "en-US"`

6. Close window and be prompted to save.
7. Re-start VS code

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: This was the easiest, immediately working way for me. thanks!

Answer (score 137):

- Open VScode
- Press F1 and type 'display'
- Choose 'Configure display language'
- Select your language. On top are installed languages, below are other languages. The one you select will be installed as an extension.
- Accept to restart.
- you can see that the language you choose has been added to the extensions by selecting 'extension' icon on the left toolbar (look for 'xxx language Pack')

More info [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales)

Previous original answer (for older vscode):

- Open VSCode
- Press F1 and type 'language'
- Choose "Configure language" in the menu
- Change the 'locale' value. See '[here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/locales)' for available languages.

> `Example: "locale":"en-US"`

- Save
- Restart vscode

Comment: This doesn't work when you accidently changed the language to anything else than english. In case the current display language is german than you need to press F1 and type "Sprache konfigurieren". So the OP would need to type the chinese translation of "Configure language" in order to open the configuration file.

Comment: This is actually shortcut to open C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User as in answer by Wosi

Comment: Since the `locale.json` didn't exist since I ran this command in VS Code, this was the more helpful answer for me =)

Comment: This is also published at [visualstudio](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales)

Comment: If you get the error `Value is not accepted. Valid values: "XX"` after reboot, it's because you didn't restart every instances of vscode.

Answer (score 33):

Since my Chinese (or whatever language this is in your screenshot) is pretty bad I describe how to set the display language to american English **without** using VSCode.

- Close VSCode
- Open the file **locale.json** with a text editor (I suggest **not** to use VSCode).

  On **Windows** the file is located under `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`

  On **Linux** it's under `$HOME/.config/Code/User`

  On a **Mac** it's under `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User`
- Change the file content to

  ```
  {
       "locale":"en-US"
  }
  ```
- Open VSCode again

Comment: This answer seems outdated, there is any "locale.json" in the specified directory on Windows after closing VS Code v1.8.1, you must create the file from zero with the specified content in the answer (or change the language directlly in the UI by pressing F1 and search for the option in your main language to create the locale.json file)

Comment: If you get the error `Value is not accepted. Valid values: "XX"` after reboot, it's because you didn't restart every instances of vscode.

Comment: @ElektroStudios `locale.json` will be created in the specified directory once you have followed the steps from the [answer of Eric Bole-Feysot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36884109) once.

Comment: I don't have AppData folder, what now?

Answer (score 4):

For Windows user,

Go to following folder,
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

Edit locale.json or create it, if not exist with following content

```
{
 "locale":"en"
}
```

Supported locales can be found in the following links
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761051

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

1. Preferences->Extension
2. search "LanguageName Language Pack"
   (example) "English Language Pack"
3. Install

Comment: This is the easiest way and worked for me under Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [VSCode Display Language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales).

1. Change language for temporary folder

click: File->Preferences->Settings, User seting json file will open and add " "locale"="en" ", save the file and restart.
Or you can use a command: >>> code . --locale=[lang] (lang refer to language code)

2. Permanently change language

Press Ctrl+Shift+P to bring up the Command Palette then start typing "config" to filter and display the Configure Language command. Add " "locale"="en" " into the Jason file, save and restart

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Community for Mac 7.0 go to

> Settings->Visual Style->User Interface Language

Answer (score 0):

For mac OS user:
At $home/Library/Application Support/Code/User, 
create a new file with name "locale.json" (it wasn't there for me), and type:

```
{
  "locale": "en-US"
}
```

Worked for me. The latter part is the same to others' answer I guess, just there wasn't "locale.json" for me so I tried creating it myself, found it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As a Ubuntu user, the only option that seemed available to me was to start Visual Studio Code at the command line, explicitly specifying the language:

```
code --locale en
```

(The interface had been in French, due to the language I'd applied for my operating system. I'm trying to learn French, but having VSCode in French was a bit much, I still need to earn money writing software )

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VS Code palette. Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
2. Type: *Display*
3. Select: *Configure Display Language*
   [image]
4. Choose the desired language