# The value obtained by VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG in vscode is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I use process.env.VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG to get the language currently focused on vscode.

My editor is in English, but the value given is indeed zh-cn. How to deal with this problem?

[image]

I am indeed a vscode downloaded in China. Can you help me thanks

Comment: Maybe if you change your locale? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868322/how-to-change-ui-language-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: I tried it and it is indeed, thank you for your answer